# i want to draw circle around my current location and find out other users which are come in range of this circle on my google map in android

Tags: android

in this my gps application i want to draw circle around my current location i did it ...but now i find out other users which are come in cirle range so i want popoup in my application screen so can anyboby help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have just to compute the distance between each point and the center of the circle.

This can be done with something like this:

```
double d2r = (180 / Math.PI);
double distance = 0;

try{
    double dlong = (endpoint.getLon() - startpoint.getLon()) * d2r;
    double dlat = (endpoint.getLat() - startpoint.getLat()) * d2r;
    double a =
        Math.pow(Math.sin(dlat / 2.0), 2)
            + Math.cos(startpoint.getLat() * d2r)
            * Math.cos(endpoint.getLat() * d2r)
            * Math.pow(Math.sin(dlong / 2.0), 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double d = 6367 * c;

    return d;

} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and then

if (distance < CIRCLE_RADIUS) 
   //The point is inside circle.

Comment: i want to find distance withput math calculation i want to find distance using kml and i did it....but i cant able to find distance for multiple users..if u want so can i put my code here..???

Comment: so, the current status, is you can find the distance for user but not for all users? I don't understant your problem. You have just to create a loop like "do while" for each one of your user, compute the distance, than create a list or an array and add the user in this list if dstance is smaller than your radius. I think you need to explain a little bit more your issue! Your question is only 3 lines long!

Comment: In my problem i draw circle around my locaition of particular radius but now i want to check one thing if other users will come in my that circle range so i get one alert box so how can i check other user distance to my cirlce radius tell me proper method or logic....

Answer (score 0):

If you know the coordinates of the center of the circle and a friend you can call the static method Location.distanceBetween() to find the distance. As you must know the size of your circles radius its just a compare of the result of distanceBetween() and your radius.